# Equivalent conjecture to Goldbach's conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

I'm reading a paper regrading the *basis orders*. In that paper, I met with the following statement:

$$3(\mathbb{P}\cup\{0 \})=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$$,

Which, by definition, states that primes form basis of order $3$(Must admit that I still don't really know what it really means).

My question is, why the statement "every integer greater than $2$ can be represented as sum of three prime" equivalent to Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: Because take an even number $n$, if $n+2$ is the sum of three primes, then one of those primes must be even, and hence is $2$. It follows that $n$ is itself the sum of $2$ primes.

Comment: Hello. That's case is obvious, but what happens with the case in which $n$ is odd integer?

Comment: I would interpret it this way : Every natural number $n>1$ can be represented by the sum of three numbers, being either a prime or $0$. If exactly three numbers are required (not at most three numbers), then $0$ must be added becuase $5$ would otherwise not have a representation.

Comment: Yes. But why it equivalent to Goldbach's conjecture?

Comment: @russiankingdom Then use Golbach to write $n-3$ as sum of two primes.

Comment: One direction of the equivalence can be shown as follows : Suppose, Goldbach's conjecture is true. Then, every even number greater than $n>2$ is a sum of two primes and every odd number greater than $n>5$ is a sum of three primes becaus $n-3>2$ is a sum of two primes. I do not know how to prove the opposite direction.

Comment: Even if every $n$ can be represented by the sum of three primes, it is not clear if for some specific $n$, a representation $n=3+p+q$ is possible. So, then $n-3$-argument is not sufficient.

Comment: @Peter look at my first comment. It is not just the odd numbers that are the sum of three primes but also the even numbers.

Comment: OK, this is convincing.